# ng-animate ng-include $template cache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

OK I have the following:

```
var app = angular.module('Anim',["ngAnimate"]);
app.controller('ParentController',function($scope){
});
app.directive('home', function ($animate) {
  return {
      templateUrl: 'pantone-inner-home.html',
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
          $scope.closemenu = function closemenu(){
            $scope.$parent.mainmenulink = '';
          };
      }
    };
});
app.directive('menuToggle', function () {
  return {
      templateUrl: 'menu-toggle.html',
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.openmenulink = function openmenulink(){
            $scope.mainmenulink = 'pantone-section.html';
        };
      }
    };
});
```

using angulaJS 1.2 and ng-animate my problem is it only ever animates on the first load after that is get's pulled from the $templatecache which is great since it reduces my template load time buut it ruins my anaimations. 
How do i keep templatecache and use ng-include templates... 
I have put up a plunkr  that reproduces this error:
 http://plnkr.co/edit/1n47lJfxtrDH8xPvCSsW?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this isn't due to `$tempateCache` at all.  Instead, it looks more like you've got your `ng-enter` classes in slightly the wrong place.  They should be attached to the `.nav` class as that is the element that is performing the `ng-include`, so it should be there that the `ng-enter` styles and transitions are applied.

I've forked and updated the plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jSEjM4IiVFrHYTWHrKjZ?p=preview

Comment: damn you right!!!
how would i go about aniamting the custom directive after the ng-include runs?
it doesn't matter thats a whole different question! thank you :D

Comment: One approach would be to supply an `onload` function on the `ng-include`. This function could set a value in the scope that could then be used with an `ng-class` to add a class to an element inside the custom directive template somewhere, thereby allowing use of `ng-add`/`ng-remove`.

Comment: you dear sir are a Effing genius!! thank you for the time taken to look over this, much apprictaed it's been driving me up the wall...